# Web is not applied js and css

Tags: github, github-pages

I don't know why my web does not apply js and css after using pages of github.
My web link: https://binhxoay1234.github.io/vozer.github.io/,
and web git hub: https://github.com/binhxoay1234/vozer.github.io.
Can you help me with this, i have been sitting for 2 hours but still have no solution
i'm very grateful if you help me, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... According to the error messages on your browser's development console (if you're not familiar with that, now is the perfect time to look into it) some of the referenced files (JS and/or CSS) are not found at the URL(s) where you're looking for them.

Comment: thanks for helping me, i appriciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your bootstrap import. I was able to get it looking like [this](https://i.imgur.com/7Qg49uH.png) by changing this line in the head of your index.html from

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

to

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">`

from the [bootstrap docs.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Pleased to help! Please consider marking this as the correct solution using the checkmark.